# STM32f103 and St-link

Tags: stm32, keil

I designed this circuit on PCB (ARM:STM32f103)
[image]

My crystal freq is 25Mhz. After connecting st-link in Keil I got this error:

> Invalid ROM Table ST-Link

However, after changing the crystal value to 8Mhz on my PCB, it works fine. I need to know

1) For any value of external crystals, how can I set this value in Keil for st-link to program my MCU without any problems?

2) Keil->configure->Target-> Xtal value is important? what about Keil->configure->Debug->St-link ->Trace->Core clock value.

Comment: I don't know Keil settings, but HSE external crysal must be in 4 - 16 MHz range. Please see *Table 22* in datasheet.

Comment: Tagli, I really appreciate your good tip that I didn't pay attention to it.

Comment: Datasheet is always important to read. Ideally even before the schematics task.

Answer (score 3):

Please read the datasheet. Refer to external click crystal HSE characteristics. 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The value of the crystal must be between 4-16Mhz.